# iOS library serialize/deserialize JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need an xcode library to serialize/deserialize to/from JSON

Comment: Did you try a to search for JSON serialize/deserialize? Because them would have found: [`NSJSONSerialization `](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a native API for this called [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html).

This will serialise and deserialise JSON.

Comment: can this native API deserialize the JSON object into  a class that I specify ?

Comment: @ABOUNASRAlfred the class is not determined by you the class is determined by the JSON and will usually be a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`. There's nothing stopping you from using the dictionary or array to then populate a custom class of your own though. `initWithDictionary` or something.